# Query the text of an oracle-view via C# / Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle.manageddataaccess

With the old data-provider from MS **System.Data.OracleClient** I was able to query the text of an oracle-view with the following code:

```
...
cmd.CommandText = "select text from all_views where view_name = 'MY_VIEW'";
var viewText    = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
...
```

Now with the new (native) provider **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** this isn't possible anymore. The same code (and any other attempts) run without exception, but the result is always String.Empty (not null).

In fact, the command is executed (all other columns from **all_views** are queriable). Only 'text' remains empty. Therefore I am afraid of a mistake in the oracle-provider.

Does anybody know an answer or an alternative method?
Thx in advance.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featData.htm#i1007197

Comment: Thx David. Problem solved and this doc is very helpful, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` in `all_views` is a `long` for backwards compatibility reasons but that data type has been deprecated for a couple of decades now so it's often a pain to work with.  You probably can adapt your code to work with a `long` correctly but you're probably better off using

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'VIEW', 'MY_VIEW' )
  from dual
```

to get the DDL for the view as a `clob` instead.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thank you very much for your answer. This solves the problem an you're right: the long datatype is the reason. The function "dbms_metadata.get_ddl" returns the text as CLOB. And this is readable with the ManagedDataAccess Provider :-)